# How does one go about deleting a tree made up of nodes with pointers to each other?

Tags: c++

I have a class that is a tree that is made up of nodes that have parent, leftChild, and rightSibling pointers. My intent was to delete the tree from the bottom to the top. With the way I have it set up currently, the nodes don't get "deleted" because the nodes that point to them are still pointing to that location, which should be nothing which causes an error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked around but I haven't found a situation that is similar to mine.

```
OrgTree::~OrgTree()
{
    TreeNode * curr = root;

    while (curr->leftChild != nullptr)
    {
        if (curr->leftChild != nullptr)
        {
            curr = curr->leftChild;
        }
    }

    while (root != nullptr)
    {
        if ((curr == root) && (curr->leftChild == nullptr))
        {
            delete(curr);
        }
        else
        {
            if (curr->leftChild == nullptr)
            {
                curr = curr->parent;
            }

            TreeNode * temp = curr->leftChild;
            TreeNode * prev = curr;

            while (temp->rightSibling != nullptr)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->rightSibling;

                if (temp->rightSibling == nullptr)
                {
                    prev->rightSibling = nullptr;
                }
            }

            while (temp->leftChild != nullptr)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->leftChild;

                if (temp->leftChild == nullptr)
                {
                    prev->leftChild = nullptr;
                }
            }

            delete(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The old "let me write some code, and the idea will come to my mind" almost never works.  Plan on paper how you want to do this first.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not quite sure what you mean by relinking the nodes. Do you mean the creating of temp and prev?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had written this problem out and made a visual representation of what I want done. My approach didn't work and I'm at a roadblock. I'm not sure how else your comment can help.

Comment: @JackKeller I had misread the code, I've retracted my comment. Though I'm not sure I follow the reasoning behind what your destructor does.

Comment: You shouldn't write one line of code until you come up with the procedure on paper first, including covering all of the issues such as nodes pointing to themselves.  If what you wrote on paper is sound, then you write the code to mimic what you have.  If there is a small bug, then you run the program in the debugger to see where your code goes against your plan and correct that bug.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I need the deconstructor of the tree to free up the memory of each individual node so as not to cause any memory leaks.

Comment: @JackKeller My confusion is the reasoning behind why you iterate over the nodes the way you do.

Comment: @JackKeller -- Have you considered breadth-first search instead of traversing the tree in the way you're doing it now?  Using BFS, the deletion becomes a lot easier.

Comment: One possibility is for `TreeNode` to have a destructor that deletes its children. Then the destructor for `OrgTree` consists of `delete root;`. That's simple, but it uses stack space proportional to the depth of the tree.

Comment: @JackKeller [Uncompiled / untested example of BFS](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b560bb067cd04040)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so... Your algorithm looks like:

- Travel to deepest, left-most node.
- Move up (1) to parent
- Travel to right-most sibling of that node AND Unlink that node from prev
- Travel to Deepest, left-most node of that node AND unlink that node from prev
- delete whatever node you land on

---

My first thought is to use an `std::vector<TreeNode*>` when allocating the nodes and just deleting the nodes from the list.  If I knew how many nodes I needed before constructing the tree, I might even be tempted to use `std::vector<TreeNode>` and hand out pointers like `&myVector[mCursor++]`.

---

But, if we were going to go with the fully dynamic route and avoid pre-steps to track nodes as they are allocated, then what you are trying to do is called [Post Order Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)).  There are several algorithms for post-order traversal of a binary tree, including ones without recursion.  [Here's one that uses a stack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-postorder-traversal-using-stack/) (although you should use `std::stack<TreeNode*>`).

Here's the recursive code [Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/):

```
/* Given a binary tree, delete its nodes according to the
  "bottom-up" postorder traversal. */
static void deletePostorder(TreeNode* node)
{
     if (node == NULL)
        return;

     // first recur on left subtree
     deletePostorder(node->leftChild);

     // then recur on right subtree
     deletePostorder(node->rightSibling);

     // now deal with the node
     delete node;
}

OrgTree::~OrgTree()
{
   deletePostorder(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over TreeNode?

If so, you can make the TreeNode destructor delete their left and right child and your top level destructor is just

```
OrgTree::~OrgTree() {
  delete(root);
}
```